# Formik's setFieldValue doesn't work with value coming from Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, react-context

I'm using AWS Amplify and Formik in my React Native app. There's a screen in which a list of members will be displayed, and when the screen is loaded, the current user will be added by default to the list. Here's what I had before and works perfectly (I can see the current user in the list on the screen).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (values.members.length === 0) {
       Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
         const owner: Member = {
           id: user.attributes.sub,
           name: user.attributes.name,
         };

         setFieldValue('members', [owner]);
       });
    }
  }, []);
```

But, then, I created a `UserContext` and decided to replace the call to the amplify function `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` with the user coming from the `UserContext`. Here's the new code:

```
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (values.members.length === 0) {
      const owner: Member = {
        id: user.attributes.sub,
        name: user.attributes.name,
      };

      console.log("Owner", owner); // This displays the current user in the console

      setFieldValue('members', [owner]);
    }
  }, []);
```

As I've commented in the code, the `console.log()` displays the current user, so the `UserContext` is working correctly, but for some reason `setFieldValue` doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

**UPDATE:**

I figured if I put `setFieldValue()` in the second code inside a `setTimeout` it works. But, in that case, shouldn't it also work if I changed `useEffect(() => {}, [])` to `useEffect(() => {}, [user])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You issue is because of an [existing formik issue](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/930). So till it is fixed, just live with setTimeout or the solution you have mentioned.

Also see some of the other alternatives mentioned in the same link if it is useful.

Comment: That explains it, then. Thank you! I was so sure it didn't have anything to do with Formik that I didn't even look for an issue there. In that case, my solution in the other answer is better than using a `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. I'm posting this as an answer, but I'm still looking for an answer as to why this even happens.

```
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [owner, setOwner] = useState(null as Member | null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (values.members.length === 0) {
      setOwner({
        id: user.attributes.sub,
        name: user.attributes.name,
      });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFieldValue('members', [owner]);
  }, [owner]);
```